# Using CTE with while loop in SQL server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to use CTE with while loop. Is it possible

my code:

```
; with myCTE(a,b)
(
 select .,. from abc
)
while exist (select * from mycet) -- causing issue
```

Please suggest some solution.

Regards,
Anuprita

Comment: not sure what you want to do but, a while loop is not the right way to think about it. SQL is a set based langauge.

Comment: SQL Server (title) or MySQL (tag)? For SQL Server, you can't combine these features.

Comment: just move the CTE into a derived table.  however it will have to rerun the query for each iteration.  I'd try to avoid the loop, if you can't I'd store the results in a table variable and loop over that: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1578198/65223

Comment: You can populate a temp table from a CTE, then use the temp table for your loop, see this example in SQLFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/634db4/3.

Answer (score 2):

No,  [the documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) states:

> A CTE must be followed by a single SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE
>   statement that references some or all the CTE columns.

But you should use a set based approach instead of loops anyway. Apart from that, it is not clear what your query should return.