# Reading into each element of SQL Server Macro list

Tags: sql, sql-server, macros

I wanted to know if there is a concept of a macro in SQL Server, and if lists reading is possible in a macro?

For instance, if I have a bunch of dates I want to input in a list, like below (consider the below 4 macro variables of Start_Date, End_Date, Prev_Date and Table_Name)

```
Start_date=[1/1/2020, 2/1/2020, 3/1/2020]
End_date=[1/31/2020, 2/29/2020, 3/31/2020] 
Prev_Date=[12/31/2019,1/31/2020,2/29/2020]
Table_Name=[P1,P2,P3]

--and have a SQL script which runs like below

select a.metric1 as &Table_Name,
       b.metric2,
       c.metric3 
into &Table_Name(i)
from 
(
select metric1 from table
where Date between &Start_Date(i) & &End_Date(i)
)a
inner join 
(
select metric2 from tableX
where date<=&End_Date(i)
)b
on a.key=b.key
inner join 
(
select metric3 from tableX
where date<=&Prev_Date(i)
)c
on a.key=c.key;
```

So at the end of this code, we'd have 3 tables P1,P2,P3 create which I will then union together. Essentially, P1 is for between Start_Date 1/1/2020 & End Date 1/31/2020 and Prev_Date 12/31/2019 and so on...

I have &Prev_Date(i) as some form of a counter of reading into the elements of 3 macro variable lists.

Comment: Personally I would use a table variable to store a collection of values like that. But no there is macro as you describe, T-SQL is primarily set based with a few procedural constructs.

Comment: Thanks Dale,  how would i use a table variable in this context?

Comment: How are you going to provide data? is that in the script itself? Do you need to automate this, like passing parameterized data from outside and get the results returned?

Comment: A quick google shows [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578198/can-i-loop-through-a-table-variable-in-t-sql)